# Apache Response Time

Tags: apache

I have been using Apache on my local LAN. The problem is that i recently installed APC (along with PHP5-dev and apache2-dev). Now the response time of Apache has reduced. It roughly takes 2 seconds to for a php page to load, where as earlier it took around 500ms. Although in firebug is shows the old response times.

Why is this so? How should i fix it?

Thank you very much.

**Update** Which server should I install incase I reinstall it? I want really blazing fast LAN response times from my server. I am planning ubuntu desktop 9.04. Or should I use ubuntu 8.04 server? or ubuntu 9.04 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know it's a server issue? I'd try on a fresh install of an OS or at least a browser, if you use firefox you could possibly have an addin interacting badly with your site. Check out the client side first before assuming it's Apache. Second APC may be the problem. SInce the site's on your lan it's probably low traffic. APC might be spending time cashing the code but have to recash it every time the PHP page is loaded since traffic is so light.

Comment: I disabled APC, now I still getting those slow speeds. It was working fine till I installed apache2-dev apc etc. using this guide: http://www.blogovela.com/installing-apc-on-ubuntu-804-hardy-heron-0314.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some very high memory usage for each time PHP starts. Check `top` in bash while you open a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want/need blazing response time you should start reading the books or contacting a professional performance tuningjexpert for you don't seem to have any measurement concept at all.

What I mean is the presence of statistics: LINUX stats, APC stats, apache stats, (php stats ?), LAN/WLAN stats and the like.

Measure and analyse your environment rather than guessing. 
It breaks my heart when Waage recommends to use the top command ... Little wonder that he never answered after your > top shows 1.0 and apache shows 1.0 ...

In your case you need to get a clear picture regarding end-2-end response-time.
(You should have set up a procedure long ago. No you are in trouble and you haven't even prepared for firebattling)

The reason for all my writing so far is the existence of my complete apache/php/MySQL realtime monitor. Supports LINUX and wINDOWS. Have a look at the picture ... (Put some pictures here but I am not allowed to attach pictures. My God.)

In case you are still interested in a solution (your blog entry is quite old)
please send me an e-mail. I will then send some documentation.

Also try to improve your apache-log-file info. Check following URL. Really good for a first step as you will get true apache response time from now on:

http://www.ducea.com/2008/02/06/apache-logs-how-long-does-it-take-to-serve-a-request/

Best regards,
linuxaomi